# Como conectar controladores de Angular con Ionic 3

Tags: ionic

Estoy empezando a trabaja con Ionic 3 en la cual no me crea ningún archivo app.js como he visto en tutoriales y post.
He creado el archivo "app.js" y lo he cargado al archivo index.html de mi aplicación ionic pero me aparece un error: Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
Estoy pensando que es la importanción o algo por el estilo... quisiera que me dijeran como es la exportación correcta de controladores de angular para poder utilizarlos en mis pages de ionic 3

archivo app.js y archivo index.html donde importo el archivo app.js

```js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccesoryBar(true);

        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();

        }
    });
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ionic App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">
 
  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps (remove if not needed) -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script><!--este es el archivo y lo importo-->
  <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.error('Error', err));
    }
  </script>-->

  <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  

</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer tienes una confusion desde la version de ionic 2 en adelante se comenzó a utilizar angular 2+ y ya no va a existir el app.js ya que angular 2 es totalmente diferente a angularjs que es la primera version donde se usaban los archivos app.js por defecto.

En vez de el app.js de forma inicial trae esto

```
<!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>
```

Este es el componente que permite inicial la aplicación en ionic, este componente se encuentra en la ruta src/app/app.component.ts

Puedes ver el ejemplo de esta [aplicacion](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app) que tiene el equipo de ionic en github llamada ionic-conference-app.

Comment: Gracias Amigo.!... por la información jeje así ya no busco en vano.
Estuve revisando la página que mencionaste y en el app.component.ts al parecer en mi poco conocimiento, declaran los métodos que se utilizan en las pages???... esa parte no la entendí.. es decir, en lugar de declarar métodos en "app.js" (que ya no existe) debemos declararlos en el app.component.ts?? o como puedo en sí.. utilizar controladores en los pages?... Te agradecería mucho si me ayudaras con esa otra duda.

Comment: Te entiendo pero la situación es la siguiente en angular 2 en adelante ya no existen controladores sino componentes, desde mi punto de vista lo que necesitas en investigar un poco de angular 2 en adelante  esta es la nueva estructura https://angular.io/guide/architecture, tambien  este un tutorial de ionic https://www.uno-de-piera.com/primera-aplicacion-ionic-3-desde-0/

Comment: Muchas gracias! amigo!